# cant print big strings in javascript with echo php

Tags: javascript, php, string, integer

I have saved in my database some big string.. when I echo this string in php, it seems right, but when I echo in javascript something going wrong..
In javascript i use BigInteger.min.js and everything is right.

Actually when I do:

```
echo 'value: '.$row['number'].'  <br>  ' ;
```

I see:

```
value: 120118115121102112105113101111105118160154160166108115575502249857345147172085249
```

But when I try to do the same in javascript:

```
document.write(<?php echo $row['number'];?>);
```

I saw:

1.201181151211021e+80.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not wrapped in quotes that "string" is handled as an integer. To have it display as a string wrap it in quotes in your code:

```
document.write("<?php echo $row['number'];?>");
```